# Html encode in perl excluding html tags

Tags: perl

```
$encoded = encode_entities($input, '<>&"');
```

This will encode the <,>,&,".But how to exclude these things from the encoding??

Comment: Those are the only characters you need to encode in HTML. If you feel the urge to encode others then you should probably fix your system to consistently use UTF-8 throughout.

Comment: I am using these to encode gibberish characters, so i used `HTML::Entities::encode_entities_numeric($converted_string,'^\n\x20-\x25\x27-\x7e');`                                                                                                  But it is encoding all the html tags also

Comment: That's because `<` (0x3C), `>` (0x3E), and `"` (0x22) are all in the range 0x20 - 0x25 or 0x27 - 0x7E. Everything *not* in those ranges, plus newlines, will be encoded.

Answer (score -1):

There is an example in [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/lib/HTML/Entities.pm):

> ```
>  $encoded = encode_entities($input, '^\n\x20-\x25\x27-\x7e');
> ```